# Vuejs Options API function import: Gives uncaught (in promise) typeerror: _ctx.functionName is not a function

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, typeerror, vue-options-api

Suppose I have a function named formatStr in global.js file:

```
export const formatStr = () => {
 return 'something';
}
```

Now, I am importing it a component say OptionComponent.vue:

`import { formatStr } from '@/vue/folder/global';`

The component is written in Options API in Vue3. Now when I try to use the function inside template  I get this error that it is not a function. But I can use it inside script tag of the component. What is the way to using a function in Options API? Should I declare a local variable or function for that imported function?

I wrote a local function that calls the imported function and then used the local function instead of the imported function.

I expect a clean way to handle function import in Vue Options API.

Comment: Assign functions to the [methods](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#methods) block to make them available in your template... `methods: { formatStr }`

Comment: Okay, it works. But I thought that was not  necessary in Vue3.

Comment: In the Composition API perhaps but the Options API is purposefully close to Vue2